# Rspec not working properly: unable to find matching line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Im writing an rspec which does this

```
require 'rails_helper' 
 feature 'People can sign-in' do

  include TestFactories
  include Devise::TestHelpers

 scenario 'Log in successfully' do
 # request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = '/'
 visit root_path
 @user = authenticated_user #defined in test_factories.rb
 sign_in @user
 sign_in @user
  end
 end
```

But when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
```

I already tried to add:

```
request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = '/'
```

But this doesn't help. Ant clues what I should do to get this working?

Answer (score -1):

I just encountered the same error.

Here was my quick fix, tailor it to your needs.

```
post "/some/page", {:first_name => "john", :last_name => "doe"}, {:referer => '/some/page'}
```